# GWT regexp only matches the last occurence

Tags: java, regex, gwt

I try to parse the string `/param1=value1/param2=value2`, to extract the param/value pairs with this code :

```
  public static void main(String[] foo) {

    RegExp regExp = RegExp.compile("(/(\\w+)=(\\w+))*", "g");

    MatchResult matchResult = regExp.exec("/param1=value1/param2=value2");

    for (int i = 0; i < matchResult.getGroupCount(); i++) {
      System.out.println("group" + i + "=" + matchResult.getGroup(i));
    }

  }
```

which outputs :

```
group0=/param1=value1/param2=value2
group1=/param2=value2
group2=param2
group3=value2
```

I tried with and without the "`g`" (global) flag.

Why does it capture only `param2=value2` and not also `param1=value1`?

Comment: remove the `asterisk` from your regex.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `Window.Location.getParameter(String)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `asterisk`(`*`) from your regex.